# Python Histogram from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram from this data set:

[image: My DataSet]

I would like to have a graph like this:

[image: Graph I want]

I wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('Data_Istogramma.csv', sep=';')
plt.hist(x =(data.iloc[0,1:6],data.iloc[1,1:6]),bins = 5,edgecolor = 'black',label =['80%','76.8%'])
plt.show()
```

Once run, I get this graph:

[image: Graph I get]

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Please provide the data in raw format, then I can load it and experiment with plotting histograms

Comment: Since your data already contains frequency aggregates, you should use a bar chart to visualize it instead of histogram function. Histogram function does the binning for you if you provide microdata. Which is not what you want here. Check out the second example here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

Comment: @GustavRasmussen LP;>850;850-700;700-425;425-250;<250;MTOT
80;47.83;5.24;18.74;22.22;34.92;137.75
76.8;61.47;6.18;54.37;3.22;16.52;156.38. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @PushkarNimkar Thank you! I'll check that out

Comment: @MattiaMuracchioli Thanks, I updated my answer now with your values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to define rows, and header row as index:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eighty = [47.83, 5.24, 18.74, 22.22, 34.92, 137.75]
seventy_six = [61.47, 6.18, 54.37, 3.22, 16.52, 156.38]
LP = [">850",
      "850-700",
      "700-425",
      "425-250",
      "<250",
      "MTOT"
      ]

df = pd.DataFrame({'80': eighty,
                   '76.8': seventy_six},
                  index=LP)

ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.show()
```

Returns:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ploty](https://plotly.com/) to achieve this. You can install plotly by `pip install plotly`

```
#sample df
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'lp':[70,85],
    '>850':[34,39],
    '700-850':[38,39],
    '425-700':[13,34],
    '250-425':[16,2],
    '<250':[25,10]
    
})

#reshape the df
df=df.melt(id_vars=['lp'])  
 
#use plotly library
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='70', x=df[df['lp']==70]['variable'], y=df[df['lp']==70]['value']),
    go.Bar(name='85', x=df[df['lp']==85]['variable'], y=df[df['lp']==85]['value']),
])
# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

[image]